# How do I get Azure Subscription and Tenant in ADF

Tags: parameters, azure-data-factory

So I am building a pipeline in ADF to be used for failure notifications. There is a web function that creates a record in our ticketing system. In the body of the web activity, I have the URL of the pipeline that failed. Since we have multi resource groups representing Dev, Test & Prod, I want to parameterize the resource group and subscription so it can dynamically change as it is deployed to each environment.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to get the values into the pipeline. I feel as if it should be easy and straight forward, but I do not see it in the dynamic content section.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add it as a (global) [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters)?

Comment: @rickvdbosch, possibly. The issue I am having is the syntax to pull the values in.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, I also realized since my organization uses ansible to push code. I can just parameterize in my code and as a pipeline variable. Just wasn't sure if there existed syntax within ADF.

Comment: @cquadrini we must manually put the subscription name value into the global parameter, then we can use it for every pipeline in the Data Factory. We can use `@pipeline().globalParameters.parameterName` to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  @Leon Yue said, [Global parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters) are constants across a data factory that can be consumed by a pipeline in any expression.

We can create **Global parameters** here and pass the value to it and using `@pipeline().globalParameters.parameterName` to get the value in the pipeline.
[image]